# attempt to use array_map in a class is resulting in a warning

Tags: php

A new class has been created for a PHP project as follows:

```
class Cleanse
{

    # trims leading and trailing spaces
    public static function trimmer($values)
    {       
        return is_array($values) ?
                    array_map('trimmer', $values) :
                    trim($values);
    }

}
```

However, when trying to use this functionality like so:

```
$values = Cleanse::trimmer($_POST);
```

the following warning message is returned:
**Warning: array_map() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'trimmer' not found or invalid function name in (class file path) on line 41.**

What is wrong with this code and/or this approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `trimmer` is a static method of `Cleanse`, it should be

```
array_map('Cleanse::trimmer', $values) // PHP >= 5.2.3
```

or

```
array_map(array('Cleanse', 'trimmer'), $values) // PHP < 5.2.3
```

See [Callbacks](http://php.net/manual/language.types.callable.php) for the correct syntax to use for callbacks.